# In this sentence, what parts of speech are the words 'next' and 'last'?

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

Could someone please tell me what the word 'next' and 'last' are? I mean the word class.

'it's your turn next ish' 
'I read the letters last ish'

Thank you!

Comment: _Next_ and _last_ are ordinal quantifiers (_two_ is a cardinal number; _second_ is an ordinal number). Note that _next_ and _last_ take the same superlative _-st_ suffix as _first_ and _oldest_. And _first ish_ works just as well as _next ish_ and _last ish_. Especially if you're using _ish_ as the slang term for _issue_, as of a science fiction magazine.

Comment: But *ish* isn't *Issue* in the above context.  It's really just *nextish* and *lastish* with the *ish* suffix separated by a blank.  And the function of the suffix is to modify it's associated word with "about" or "approximately".  (My best shot would be that the words *next* and *last* function as adverbs, but there are other religions which would say no.)

Answer (score 2):

In your sentences, next is an adverb.

Comment: Please justify that strange assertion.